# Selection anchor is missing in Arcmap/Aligning a shapefile to another shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing

Features got accidently moved without me noticing it before saving the edits, now I need to align them with the shapefile that is still correct.

To do this I thought I could best use the anchor points combined with snapping. But to my surprise there is no anchor point when selecting a feature.

What can I do to make it reappear?

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if your shapefiles have different coordinate systems, the selection anchor will not show. The problem was that the data frame had UMTS + WGS84 and the shapefile that I was editing had just WGS84.

I projected it to UMTS and the selection anchor appeared. I don't know exactly why you cannot have a selection anchor when you're not in the same projection as the dataframe, but it probably has to do with inaccuracy problems?

Anyway, I should watch more carefully if my coordinate systems match next time.

Answer (score 0):

The selection anchor can't be deleted / turned off / removed, so all I can think of is that you've got a multi-part feature where the other part is off screen and thus the selection anchor, which is in between the two features, is off screen.

Otherwise, you might try posting to the ESRI GeoNet site...